# Angularjs best way to have database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, angularjs

So I am new to `angularjs` and I still haven't found the best way to make a database connected with `Angular.js` and the most secure way of doing so. I was thinking of doing it using `PHP` & `MySQL`.
So I am asking if somebody could tell me whether or not this is a good way of doing it.

Comment: Expose an API on the server (with PHP/MySQL or any other server-side language/database combination) and request data from it via AJAX (which Angular simplifies by providing the `$http` service).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more.If you can that would be nice.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can explain. Write a PHP script that interacts with the database in whatever way you need it to and returns data (in JSON format for example). Request that page via AJAX. Parse the returned data on the front end.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource. If you 
have restful resources defined on the back end, then AngularJS 
$resource plays quite elegantly with them.

**Update:**

```
var User = $resource('/api/user/:id');

//create a new user
var user1 = new User();
user1.name = 'Joe';
user1.age = 32;
user1.$save();

//get and update the user with id 123
var user2 = User.get({id: 123});
user2.name += ' Smith';
user2.$save();

//delete the user 123
User.$delete({id: 123});
```

Comment: So if i got it right $resource can be used for methods that can save,delete and get? Did i got that right?

Comment: No, what you are after is not implemented in Angular. Angular is not a database. It has some functions that can help you to interact with one, but itself it does not contain database. You can use any of your favourite database such as MySQL or Mongo for instance.

Comment: But will the app still be fast if i use for example mysql or should i use some other like mongodb.(Btw i got that Angular isn't a database)